# What are the fields in a classical field theory?

Tags: tensor-calculus, covariance, classical-field-theory

Consider scalar Yukawa theory. The Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$ contains an interaction term $$\mathcal{L}_I=g\psi^*\psi\phi$$ where $\psi$ and $\phi$ are complex and real scalars respectively.

I've never really thought about what this actually means. Now for scalars this isnt really a problem - I can just think of it as a product of numbers. But what about for more complicated representations of the Poincaré group? What about for interaction terms of various representations?

Suppose I have some term in the Lagrangian of the form $$W_A W_B W_C$$ where each $W_i$ is a field transforming in a different representation of the Poincare group. Something I read earlier gave me the impression that what's really written here is the ***tensor product*** of each field, since each field lives in a different representation, i.e. a different vector space.

I've tried the case of a vector field and indeed everything works nicely. Let $A$ be a vector field, i.e. there exists a vector space $V$ with basis $\{e_\mu\}$ such that $$A=A^\mu e_\mu.$$ Now consider the following element $A^*$ in $V^*$ defined by $$A^*=A_\nu e^\nu$$ where $e^\nu$ are the basis vectors of $V^*$ satisfying $$e^\nu(e_\mu)=\delta^\nu_\mu$$ Now define a function $$f:V^*\otimes V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ by $$f(A^*\otimes A)=A^*(A)=A_\mu A^\mu$$ Hence I can put this term in my Lagrangian if I can show that it transforms as a Lorentz scalar.

The case I'm obviously interested in is when $V$ is $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ and my fields transform according to the vector representation of the Lorentz algebra, $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\rho:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ be the vector representation, $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $\rho_x$ the corresponding element of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$. Hence, under an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation we have $$A\rightarrow A+\delta A,$$ where $\delta A=\rho_x(A)$.

We also have a natural representation $(\rho^*,V^*)$ defined by $$(\rho^*_x(A^*))(A)=-A^*(\rho_x(A))$$

We also have a representation $(\bar{\rho},V^*\otimes V)$ defined by $$\bar{\rho}(A^*\otimes A)=\rho^*_x(A^*)\otimes A + A^*\otimes \rho_x(A)$$ It is then immediately clear that $f(A^*\otimes A)$ is invariant under an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation, as required.

**Question 1**: Is this a correct way of viewing things?

Comment: Sure, this is correct, but I don't see how this is anything more than a complicated rephrasing of "$A^\mu B^\mu$ is a scalar" which is taught to all sophomore physics majors. If you're only dealing with vector reps of the Lorentz group everything can be done far more efficiently with tensor indices. It automates all the stuff in your post.